# Can I Leave Ground/wires on a GFCI outlet Un-conected?

Tags: electrical

Thx for taking my question; I bought a New duplicate Outlet/Light switch/ one outlet for my bathroom. New outlet has two black ground wires; I

Comment: Use the [edit] link underneath your post to  finish writing it. Thanks.

Comment: I know your question is not finished but already something is very wrong.  Ground wires are either green or bare but never black which is normally the high wire.

Comment: .... This is why GFCIs ***GROUND*** fault circuit interruptors (keyword ground); should be connected correctly. Even the question title the answer is NO (because why wouldn't you!!!). Hopefully Larry wasn't using his computer in the rain on the subject GFCI. Be safe Larry. Always use grounds, they are there for safety, as are GFCIs.

Comment: The installation instructions are part of the Listing (UL/ETL/CSA), and they say (usually in step 7) to connect the ground wires if present.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: ThreePhase; WON"T let me ppost a photo....all work was done by me today; ALL done and working; two outlets.. GFCI and night light in one... great  NO electrician needed!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a GFCI+receptacle+switch, the 2 screws are the GFCI "Line" in, and the two wires are for the switch. The switch either connects the wires or does not.

Behind a warning sticker are the LOAD terminals, but you should not use those unless you know what you are doing.  The sticker says as much.

Comment: all worked great.. attached ground wires... and all..just Followed the older wiring/ same models of the switches/ Outlets..all fine and dandy..NO Electrician needed this time!!